# How do I get 14.04.5 to detect wireless on my Mac Powerbook? The driver is installed

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, broadcom

I've installed the driver, but no wireless networks appear in the network manage. A message appeared that said the auto-detect is disabled. This is the information I received from troubleshooting the wireless network 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23812740/

```
 ########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Jan 2017 14:59 CST -0600

Booted last: 16 Jan 2017 14:29 CST -0600

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-59-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 18:02:23 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################


02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331]

04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller [11c1:5901] (rev 08)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. ADNS-5700 Optical Mouse Controller (3-button)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:821a Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################


##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################



##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:6c:8f:20:12:3b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.73  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:30a:c044:ed70::40/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::426c:8fff:fe20:123b/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2602:30a:c044:ed70:426c:8fff:fe20:123b/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2602:30a:c044:ed70:9df:87e7:8915:4f30/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16191 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22427826 (22.4 MB)  TX bytes:1832471 (1.8 MB)
          Interrupt:16 


##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search attlocal.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       853     1  0 14:29 ?        00:00:03 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############


NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        40:6C:8F:20:12:3B

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.73
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.254

    DNS:             192.168.1.254

  IPv6 Settings:
    Address:         2602:30a:c044:ed70::40
    Prefix:          128
    Gateway:         fe80::ea33:81ff:fe68:ed90

    Address:         2602:30a:c044:ed70:9df:87e7:8915:4f30
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         fe80::ea33:81ff:fe68:ed90

    Address:         2602:30a:c044:ed70:426c:8fff:fe20:123b
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         fe80::ea33:81ff:fe68:ed90

    Address:         fe80::426c:8fff:fe20:123b
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         fe80::ea33:81ff:fe68:ed90

    Address:         2602:30a:c044:ed70::40
    Prefix:          128
    Gateway:         ::




##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=40:6C:8F:20:12:3B,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you need to install the correct driver this way:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Hey thank you. I used those lines to install the driver and its working! Appreciate the help.